# Go to URL from input dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, forms, redirect, input

I have a dropdown on my website, where users can select different site-names.
Next to the dropdown I have a submit button.

I would like users to select a site-name, from the dropdown, and when they click on submit they should be redirected to a specific url, with the dropdown value appended.

```html
<form id="form" method="get">
   <option value="1">Website Name 1</option>
   <option value="2">Website Name 2</option>
   <option value="3">Website Name 3</option>

   <button class="btn" type="submit">GO!</button>
</form>
```

Example case:

- Users selects "Website Name 2"
- User clicks "GO!" button
- Site opens a new window with target "https://example.com/site/2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. However you can try below way.
In the dropdown value add a complete url which you want to redirect to instead of just value and on button click redirect to that site.

Make sure button type is not 'submit' and attach a click event with a javascript funtion.
In the javascript function read the selected value from the dropdown and use

```
window.location.href
```

to redirect to that site.

```js
function redirect() {
  var value = document.getElementById("site").value;
  window.location.href = value;
  return ;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" >
<select name="site" id ="site">
   <option value="https://Google.com/1">Google</option>
   <option value="https://stackoverflow.com/2">StackOverflow</option>
</select>
   <button class="btn" type="button" onclick="redirect()">GO!</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this functionality. I prefer having minimal HTML and handling everything in the JavaScript. We will be using an EventListener to accomplish this in my example.

Change your HTML to this:

```
<form id="form" method="get">
  <select id="selection">
     <option value="1">Website Name 1</option>
     <option value="2">Website Name 2</option>
     <option value="3">Website Name 3</option>
  </select>
   <button class="btn" type="submit">GO!</button>
</form>
```

Then you can use simple JavaScript to accomplish what you want:

```
let url = "https://example.com/site/";

document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  let selection = document.getElementById('selection').value;
  console.log(url + selection);
  window.location.href = url + selection;
});
```

This answer assumes that all URLs follow the https://example.com/site/1 format. If not, you can change the value in the option tags to be the actual URL and remove the URL prefix from the JavaScript.